# How to reduce the width of the covering layout in SlidePaneLayout Android in closed state

Tags: android, slidingmenu, sliding, slidingpanelayout

I am using android **SlidePaneLayout**, and i have two Linearlayouts inside it, **leftpane** and **rightpane** , where right pane slides over left pane in **closed state**. 
I need to reduce the width of the **rightpane** to say **250dp** .

No matter whatever width i specify, the **rightpane** covers the whole window in **closed state**. I want to **reduce the width** of **rightpane** so that i can see a little bit of the left pane on the background in **closed state**.

This is my SlidingPaneLayout xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/sp" > 

     <!-- Left side pane. (Master) --> 
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftpane" 
         android:layout_width="250dp" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:background="#DFDEFF"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
         </LinearLayout> 

         <!-- Right side page. (Slave) --> 
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightpane" 
             android:layout_width="250dp" 
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="right" 
             android:background="#CFDEFF"
             android:layout_weight="1" 
             android:orientation="horizontal">
         </LinearLayout> 

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

I have tried all the available tutorials in the net and its not working.

**Please help me.**

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView/

Comment: Thanks @Onur, i will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I've been confused about this Topic for a while aswell...
What helped me is adding a marginLeft to the **RIGHT** pane.
So you got something like this going:

```
<!-- Right side page. (Slave) --> 
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightpane" 
         android:layout_width="250dp" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="right" 
         android:background="#CFDEFF"
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp">
     </LinearLayout>
```

that adds 200dp Border on the Left side. (Which makes 200dp of the Left Pane Visible when it is closed)